# Doubt regarding Combination of Cells

Tags: resistors, batteries

[image]

I was unsure of what the voltmeter would read: the terminal voltage of the top cell, or the voltage across the parallel combination of cells. I tried calculating both ways, but both give the same answer in this case, so I'm confused.

Comment: Please show us your calculations.

Comment: My problem is not about the calculations, but which approach to take.

Comment: There is only one approach: you have to calculate the total voltage contributed from both cells. If the resistor values represent the internal resistance of each cell, then the circuit is simply a resistor and a cell in parallel with another resistor and a cell. Simple circuit rules can then be applied to calculate the resultant voltage across the voltmeter.

Answer (score 1):

Voltmeter reading will be less than 18V and more than 12V. Current flows from higher voltage to lower voltage. Connect  center O Ammeter between +ve of the battery terminals. 18v battery will be charging the 12v battery till both battery voltages are same.Then the voltmeter reading will be between 18 and 12 volts.